# TypeScript: How does typeof work when called on a class?

Tags: typescript, typeof

As far as I understand it, the TypeScript "typeof" operator performs a type query, and allows you to ensure that two objects are the same type even when that type is unnamed. However, I've found some code in production that does something like this:

```
function println (x) {
  document.write(x + '<br\>');
}

class SettingsBase {
  public static setting1: string;
  public static setting2: string;
}

class SettingsUser {
  private _settings: typeof SettingsBase;

  constructor(settings: typeof SettingsBase) {
    this._settings = settings;
  }

  public doStuff() {
    println(this._settings["setting1"]);
  }
}

class MySettings extends SettingsBase {
  public static setting1 = "foo";
  public static setting2 = "bar";
}

var baz = new SettingsUser(MySettings);
baz.doStuff();
```

In `SettingsUser`, the constructor takes an argument of type `typeof SettingsBase`. What does it mean to be "typeof" a class? I don't think this is supposed to work and I'll likely be refactoring it, but I'd like to know how it worked at all in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `typeof` keyword before a class name will extract the type of the class constructor, as opposed to just the type `Foo`, which represents an instance. So for example:

```
class Foo {}

var x: typeof Foo = Foo; // This is okay
var y: Foo = new Foo(); // Also okay
```

Comment: Also worth to note: `var z: typeof Foo = new Foo(); // NOT ok`

Comment: why use typeof Foo = Foo over new Foo() ?

Comment: So when you pass a class as a parameter, you're actually passing its constructor -- and when you call typeof on a class, you're extracting its constructor? And you can extract static properties of a class via that constructor?

Comment: @nupanick You're right and that's exactly why you would want to use `typeof`. In your example, the class `SettingsBase` only has static members, so you'd only be able to access them using the constructor (which has type `typeof SettingsBase`). Having an instance of the class would be pretty useless since there are no instance fields or methods.

Comment: Why not just access the static members with SettingsBase.setting1?

Comment: @Poku I'm guessing that there are different "settings" classes whos implementation of those static methods differ. Then different settings would be given to the constructor depending on what was desired. EG: The `MySettings` class is what is actually being given to the constructor, not `SettingsBase`. If you just used `SettingsBase.setting1`, it wouldn't allow that kind of polymorphism. In this case, `SettingsBase` is really just acting like an interface, it's probably never meant to be used directly.

Comment: @CRice, I agree. My interpretation of this code was that it was using a class like an interface. I've rewritten it to actually be an interface -- I'm not certain what motivated this design choice. 

Follow-up: is there any situation where you would want to do this rather than just using an interface?

Comment: Possibly? A class can have access modifiers (public/private/protected) where an interface can't, so maybe if you wanted to use those. But a class with only public static members really isn't any different than an interface. Otherwise, it could be that all the settings classes inherit from the base class and there are some `instanceof` checks somewhere (which can only be used with classes/prototyped things). Or maybe the original author was following a Java-ish style where a classes like that are more common? I guess I can't really say since I've never run into a use-case for it (yet).

Comment: same question. Why don't use `interface` instead of using `typeof Class`?

Comment: How can a critical piece of info such as this evade official docs?