# Effect Of TypeScript Typeof When Importing Type

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services

Consider this class:

```
import type { PublishCommand, SNSClient } from '@aws-sdk/client-sns'

export class MyPublisher {
  private readonly topicArn: string
  private readonly snsClient: SNSClient

  constructor(topicArn: string, snsClient: SNSClient) {
    this.topicArn = topicArn
    this.snsClient = snsClient
  }

  async publish(title = '', description = '', Foo: PublishCommand) {
    return this.snsClient.send(
      new Foo({
        Message: JSON.stringify({
          version: '1.0',
          source: 'custom',
          content: {
            description,
            title,
          },
        }),
        TopicArn: this.topicArn,
      }),
    )
  }
}
```

With TypeScript 5 it generates the error "This expression is not constructable." where I try to instantiate with "new Foo()". But if I add typeof just before the type of the argument Foo, it works:

```
import type { PublishCommand, SNSClient } from '@aws-sdk/client-sns'

export class MyPublisher {
  private readonly topicArn: string
  private readonly snsClient: SNSClient

  constructor(topicArn: string, snsClient: SNSClient) {
    this.topicArn = topicArn
    this.snsClient = snsClient
  }

  async publish(title = '', description = '', Foo: typeof PublishCommand) {
    return this.snsClient.send(
      new Foo({
        Message: JSON.stringify({
          version: '1.0',
          source: 'custom',
          content: {
            description,
            title,
          },
        }),
        TopicArn: this.topicArn,
      }),
    )
  }
}
```

Can someone explain to me why is that? Since I'm already importing the types only. Does it even mean something to typeof a type?

Comment: I think what you need to know is here [TypeScript: How does typeof work when called on a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48913660/2866386)

Answer (score 0):

It seem that `PublishCommand` is a class. Classes in TypeScript are a bit special, since they are both type and value at same time. Type `PublishCommand`  refers to instance of class, object which you get by executing `new PublishCommand()`, while value `PublishCommand` is constructor.

And when you try to get type of value (by using `typeof`) you get type for constructor, not for the instance.

Consider this code ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=10&ssc=19&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCCm8AO0DeBfA3AKGwFwE8l5oBBaAXjkSRwHo7omA9Afl0OLkuk-gHsAZtWT1GLdtmD8AdhDzQwALjI8Z8AO4ikACgCUOaXIUAjFbB4JRQA)):

```js
class Beep {};

type A = Beep;
type B = typeof Beep;

const a: A = new Beep();
const b: B = Beep;
```

Here `A` refers to type of instance of class `Beep`, while `B` refers to type of constructor itself.

But it's indeed seems a bit odd, that you can use `typeof` with `PublishCommand` even if you imported only type.

Answer (score 0):

Anything of type PublishCommand already is an object. That is to say it has already been instantiated. Your first example is like attempting to call `new 123()` or `new "Hello World"()`. If you are trying to make a new PublishCommand, you can simply call `new PublishCommand(...)`. It's unclear what else you would be attempting to do with this code.

To answer your question directly, PublishCommand, as a class (not just a type), is considered to have the type of `function`. This means that when you pass something with the same type as PublishCommand, it is also a `function`, and you can construct one with the `new` keyword